# what would be a proper way to write | | in ruby? A more "English" friendly way.

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out a better way to write  `| |` so it is more readable and makes sense. Is there a human way to write that?

Comment: You mean `||` which is logic `or` or `|a|` which is block parameter list?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Good point.. I might catch it wrongly..:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` - short circuit double pipe. and `&&` - short circuit double **and**.

[In Ruby, there are two sets of logical operators](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html#logical): [`!`, `&&`, `||`] and [`not`, `and`, `or`]. [`!`, `&&`, `||`]'s precedence is higher than the assignments (`=`, `%=`, `~=`, `/=`, etc.) while [`not`, `and`, `or`]'s precedence is lower. Also note that while `&&`'s precedence is higher than `||`'s, the `and`'s precedence is the same as the `or`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `or` or `and` to mean `||` or `&&` respectively.

Comment: Yes, but they aren't interchangeable since they do not have the same precendences.

Comment: Oh, that's fair enough... I always use parenthesis to make my precedence super clear because I always forget which one is taken into account first :p  So for me they tend to be interchangeable.  But I can see why they're not really.